# Teach ispell multiple-word phrases

Tags: emacs, ispell

Can I teach ispell to accept specific phrases like `et al.`, `a priori` or `in vitro` but to scold me when I use the words outside of these phrases, so that I don't use `priori` without the `a` before it?

**UPDATE** simply adding the phrase to the private dictionary does not work

**BONUS** get latex to print those phrases automatically in in italics (`\emph`)

Comment: My first thought would be try to add those phrases to your aspell or hunspell personal dictionary and see if it works.  The personal dictionary can be edited by hand.

Comment: should've written that I already tried that. Didn't work, though.

Comment: `vim` is the only program I know of that does this (though perhaps Word can?  LibreOffice cannot). I'd love to see the libraries (like ispell) to catch up.